# How to add more columns and get the total updated?

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3, 2, 5], 'col2': [9, 7, 4]})

# Adding columns
df.loc[:,'sum'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

# Adding new column
df.loc['col3'] = [4, 5, 8]
```

When I add a new column, it appends the column at the last position (after sum column). What I want instead is that it appears before the 'sum' column and adds to the 'sum'.

Comment: Pandas can't do that AFAIK. What's the use case for this? Maybe we could recommend another way to do it.

Comment: `df.loc['col3']` sets a row, not a column. You want just `df['col3']`.

Comment: Yes, just practicing. 
Problem statement was to sum two columns and then add a third column, allowing the sum to auto-refresh

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add `col3` normally, recompute the `"sum"` column and move the `"sum"` column to the last position:

```py
df["col3"] = [4, 5, 8]
df["sum"] = df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].sum(axis=1)

# "move" the sum column to the last position
df["sum"] = df.pop("sum")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  col3  sum
0     3     9     4   16
1     2     7     5   14
2     5     4     8   17
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include col3 values in sum column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3, 2, 5], 'col2': [9, 7, 4]})
df['col3'] = [4, 5, 8]
df.loc[:,'sum'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
```

If you DO NOT want to include col3 values in sum column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3, 2, 5], 'col2': [9, 7, 4]})
df.loc[:,'sum'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
df['col3'] = [4, 5, 8]
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'sum']] # reorder columns
df
```

Answer (score 0):

> *How to add more columns and get the total updated ?*
> *What I want instead is that it appears before the 'sum' column and adds to the 'sum'.*

IIUC, you need to *auto-refresh* the `sum` after creating each new column ? So, either you failed to describe your problem or I totally missed it! Anyways, for fun, you can try something like below :

```
class ArDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def addcol_withsum(self, col, vals) -> None:
        self[col] = pd.to_numeric(vals, errors="coerce")
        cols_but_sum = self.columns[~self.columns.str.fullmatch("sum")]
        self["sum"] = self[cols_but_sum].sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
        self.insert(len(self.columns)-1, "sum", self.pop("sum"))
```

Test/Output :

```
df = ArDataFrame({'col1': [3, 2, 5], 'col2': [9, 7, 4]})
print(df)

df["sum"] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
print(df)

df.addcol_withsum("col3", [4, 5, 8])
print(df)

df.addcol_withsum("col4", ["a", 1, 7])
print(df)
```

---

```
   col1  col2
0     3     9
1     2     7
2     5     4
   col1  col2  sum
0     3     9   12
1     2     7    9
2     5     4    9
   col1  col2  col3  sum
0     3     9     4   16
1     2     7     5   14
2     5     4     8   17
   col1  col2  col3  col4   sum
0     3     9     4   NaN  16.0
1     2     7     5   1.0  15.0
2     5     4     8   7.0  24.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed what I was looking for - auto-refresh sum column with each new column added